# Not listing XML elements as array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, xml-serialization

I'm having a problem with listing the Snapshots array on the root node. Here's the code:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "WebService", DataType = "WebService", IsNullable = false)]
public class WebServiceXmlElement
{
    [XmlArray("Snapshots"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Snapshot", Namespace = XmlNamespaceSettings.DefaultNamespace, IsNullable = true)]
    public NodeSnapshotElement[] Snapshots { get; set; }
}

public class NodeSnapshotElement
{ 

}

[XmlType(TypeName = "CrateSnapshot", Namespace = XmlNamespaceSettings.DefaultNamespace, IncludeInSchema = false)]
public class NodeCreateSnapshot : NodeSnapshotElement
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID", Namespace = XmlNamespaceSettings.DefaultNamespace)]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the resulting XML:

> ```
> <WebService xsd:schemaLocation="...">
>   <Snapshots/>
> </WebService>
> ```

It was supposed to be:

> ```
> <WebService xsd:schemaLocation="...">
>   <xsd:Snapshots>
>     <xsd:Snapshot>...</xsd:Snapshot>
>     <xsd:Snapshot>...</xsd:Snapshot>
>   </xsd:Snapshots>
> </WebService>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Snapshots array must be empty. Otherwise the elements are actually generated.

One note - you need to add the XmlInclude declaration for NodeCreateSnapshot class, otherwise you get a runtime exception. You can add it like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "WebService", DataType = "WebService", IsNullable = false)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(NodeCreateSnapshot))]
public class WebServiceXmlElement
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thats gotta be witchcraft... makes no sense to me... now for the icing on the cake and the answer mark: why is it showing an extra attribute for me? <xsd:Snapshot xsi:type="xsd:CreateSnapshot" ID="1c4422e8"/>

Comment: dont need to answer ill grant you the answer anyway.